# Angular Disable Animation

Tags: angular-animations, angular1.6

I am using an Angular Widget (http://alexsuleap.github.io/) and it has some animations. The widget itself does not have any option to disable the animation. But the widget is using `angular-animate.min.js`. Is it possible in some way to disable all animations that may be provided from this dependency ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is using animate method in css it is animating by opacity property you need to alter the css angular-tree-widget.css

```
treenode.ng-hide{
   opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

please add these in to your stylesheet then the animation will get stopped.

i hope it helps !!